# How to call a Fragment using intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, fragment

How to call a `fragment` from an `activity` using `intent`.

calling an `Activity` from an `Activity` is easy.

but how to call `fragmen`t?

**NOTE**

i dont have need a frameLayout.

Comment: You need to be more specific.  For example you can have another activity hold the fragment and call the that activity.  Or you can set the framelayout to hold the fragment.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @EugeneH  thanks for the quick response, I get it now. you guys gave me idea. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fragment needs to be hosting by a FragmentActivity, you can make a Intent to call a fragment from an Activity.

You need to create a FragmentManager to add your fragment in a FragmentActivity (or call another FragmentActivity via an Intent and add your fragment on it).
See this topic for more information: [Add a Fragment to an Activity at Runtime.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#AddAtRuntime)